# How can I use Jackson serialization to write a field's value but not its key

Tags: java, jackson

Suppose I have a simple class:

```
public class MyClass {
    private final String id;
    private final String additionalJson;
}
```

I want to serialize this class to JSON so that the raw value in `additionalJson` is written directly into the JSON **without** writing the field's name.
Additionally, the `id` field should be transformed so that its name is written as `identifier`.

**Example**

The values of an instance are:

```
id = 1234
additionalJson = "someKey": "someValue"
```

The serialized JSON I want should be:

```
{
  "identifier": "1234",
  "someKey": "someValue"
}
```

Changing the name of `id` is trivial to do using Mixins:

```
public class MyClassMixin {
    @JsonProperty("identifier")
    private final String id;
}
```

But I don't have a good way to include the raw JSON without adding the field's name.

My current solution is to write a custom `JsonSerializer` for `MyClass` which writes the fields value using `writeRaw()`:

```
public class MyClassSerializer extends JsonSerializer<MyClass> {
@Override
public void serialize(MyClass myClass, JsonGenerator json, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
    try {
        json.writeStartObject();
        for (Field field : myClass.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (Objects.equals(field.getName(), "additionalJson")) {
                json.writeRaw(", " + (String)field.get(angebotsTemplate));
            } else {
                json.writeObjectField(field.getName(), 
            }
        }
        json.writeEndObject();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This correctly includes the `additionalJson` value (after making the MyClass fields public) but doesn't make use of the Mixin. While I could add code to the serializer to transform the `id` name I would rather still do this in a Mixin as `MyClass` may have many fields, each with their own transformations I don't want to define in the Serializer.

Is there a way to achieve what I want, preferably relying on Mixins?

Comment: can you simply change `String additionalJson` to `Map<String, String> additionalJson` ?

Comment: I don't think so. In my frontend, `additionalJson` is filled by users writing JSON into a single textarea.